# Rotary encoders giving incorrect output

Tags: rotary-encoder

I've tried two gray code encoders recently, one from [Panasonic](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/EVQ-V9C00116E/1738883), one from [TE](https://nz.mouser.com/ProductDetail/858-EN16ABVM22B0F20).  They both exhibit a similar problem.  When connected electrically with wires, but not connected mechanically otherwise (not panel mounted, very little strain on the wires), they work fine.

But when they're in my project's enclosure, and the connecting wires are twisted around so everything fits, they'll miss changes, then overshoot.  The TE one works better than the Panasonic.  Here's the TE *in situ*.  It's connected using a white JST connector pushed onto the pins, and with the wires (red, orange, yellow, white, black) arching back over the encoder and into the PCB.

[image: encoder in situ]

Any thoughts on ways to improve this?  Is it the physical strain on the pins?

**EDIT**

I have two of the TE encoders.  One of them behaves much better than the other.  It "eventually" registers all changes.  I say "eventually", because the slowness might be cured by tweaking debouncer settings (I haven't gotten around to it yet).

Here's a bit more detail on the binary values associated with the problems.

**Problems around positions 5, 6 and 7**

When turning clockwise from position 5 (binary 7) to 6 (binary 5), no change registers.  When turning clockwise from 6 to 7 (binary 4), it briefly registers as position 4 (binary 6), then adjusts itself to 7. When turning anticlockwise from 7 to 6, the change registers.  When turning from 6 to 5, the change registers.

**Problems around positions 13, 14, 15**

When turning clockwise from position 13 (binary 11) to 14 (binary 9), nothing registers.  When turning clockwise from 14 to 15, it briefly registers as 12, then settles at 15.  When turning anticlockwise from 15 to 14, it briefly registers as 12 before settling on 14.

All of these problems relate to changes in the 2 bit.  The clockwise problems are stable.  Turning anticlockwise, it sometimes exhibits the problems, sometimes plays nicely.

Here's how the binary outputs relate to positions.

```
Position  Binary
--------  ------
0         0
1         1
2         3
3         2
4         6
5         7
6         5
7         4
8         12
9         13
10        15
11        14
12        10
13        11
14        9
15        8
```

Comment: what binary form do the errors take? are they stable? repeatable?  check that all the wires go to the right places.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні, the wires definitely go to the right place, because when the encoder is floating freely, it gives the correct results.  The errors are largely stable and repeatable, but not perfectly.  I will check later what binary form they take.  I assume you mean to discover whether multiple or single bits are in error?

Comment: yes, also if bits are stick, or slow, etc...  it could also be that the off-label use of the JST is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your debouncing parameters?

Comment: Sorry @MarcusMüller, the photo isn't ideal. Those are the power supply for the unit. The solder is lead free, so not very shiny. The connection is actually pretty good there. The black lead is actually connected to a tab in the background.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, my understanding of debouncing may be a bit naive, but I thought that would only affect transient states with a grey encoder. My observation is that even steady states are reported incorrectly.

Comment: Sounds like you just have bad connections or the encoders are bad. ‘Missing changes’ and ‘overshoot’ are not things that should happen with an absolute encoder.

Comment: "Twisting wires around" is not the same as "connected".  Debugging step one, for me, would be soldering.

Comment: I can't see the solder joints there are clearly, but some look cold.  Silver solder done right is shiny, but mostly I'm looking at the shape of the joints.  They look blobby, with no good fillet.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, there are no twisted wire connections. There might be problems with the soldering though; this PCB originally has a Panasonic encoder soldered directly to a part of the board which I've since broken off (hence the serrated edge), then a Panasonic connected via a JST using the same holes as now.That JST was removed because the pinout of the Panasonic differs from the TE. Getting the wires in the second time was tricky. Having said that, cold joints there are not consistent with observing one set of consistent bad behaviour with one encoder, and a different set of bad behaviour...

Comment: ... with another. I'm in the middle of editing the question with those observations (interrupted by sleep, then commuting).